# Why is Guilty capitalized?

Tags: capitalization

> Atticus had urged them to accept the state’s generosity in allowing them to
> plead **Guilty** to second-degree murder and escape with their lives, but
> they were Haverfords, in Maycomb County a name synonymous with jackass.

-***To Kill A Mockingbird** by Harper Lee*

In the passage above, why is "guilty" capitalized?

Comment: To emphasize the plea: Do you plead "Guilty" or "Not Guilty"? It was a style choice to do that.

Comment: @Lambie - A style choice, sure. From the official UK guidance for judges about a reduction of sentence for an early guilty plea: _"Where a guilty plea is indicated at the first stage of proceedings a reduction of one-third should be made"_

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey Guilty plea is not this "Guilty". This is meant to mirror what a defendant says in court. :)

Comment: @Lambie from Gov.uk - "Make a plea for a traffic offence
Use this service to plead guilty or not guilty to a traffic offence"

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey You aren't listening to your mother. [joke] The capital g seeks to ape the actual speech of a defendant in the text. The judge says: "How do you plead?" Defendant: "Guilty". This has zero do with the fact guilty pleas or the term guilty in legal texts **would of course not be written with an initial cap**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Guilty" here is a technical term in criminal trials - you can choose to plead "Guilty" or "Not Guilty".

If written as a normal word, the sentence would read oddly, because there is nothing for the adjective "guilty" to modify:

> * ... allowing them to plead guilty to second-degree murder ...

Using a capital letter is one of several ways to make the word stand out:

> ... allowing them to plead Guilty to second-degree murder ...

> ... allowing them to plead "guilty" to second-degree murder ...

> ... allowing them to plead *guilty* to second-degree murder ...

Comment: The capital g is meant to ape a defendant's actual speech in court.